# Vim default register overwrites clipboard (only when using Git bash console)

Tags: vim, clipboard, git-bash

Yanking/deleting text overwrites my clipboard when I use vim on Windows 10 from git bash console. For example, after I use "yy" or "dw" my clipboard content is replaced with corresponding text.

This issue does not happen when I run vim from Windows command prompt or when I use GVim, it only happens when starting vim from git bash console.

My vim version is `8.2`. My git version is `2.36.1.windows.1`.
I reinstalled vim, updated git, but it didn't help.

I noticed that after using `:set clipboard=unnamedplus`, the paste command inserts clipboard text instead of default register text, unless register is specified. For example, this inserts the right text after using `yy`:
`""p`

And this inserts the clipboard:
`p`

I have no idea if it's related but this issue started occurring while I was playing with clipboard using PyQt6 script ran from git bash console containing a line like this:

```py
QApplication.clipboard().text()
```

Edit:
`:set clipboard?` command ouputted `clipboard=unnamed` for some reason. Adding `:set clipboard-=unnamed` in .vimrc seems to "fix" the whole issue.

Comment: "*This issue does not happen when I run vim from Windows command prompt or when I use GVim, it only happens when starting vim from git bash console.*" Two different `vim`s? Different `$HOME`s and two different `.vimrc`s?

Comment: @phd No, git bash uses C:/Users/username/.vimrc, and so does gvim. There's a windows-only filename, though, and if that's used, that might be why

Comment: It looks like both: git bash, and GVim use the same `.vimrc` file, because when I change GVim settings, it affects the vim from git bash. It can be seen in this gif:
https://i.imgur.com/orArAG6.mp4

Comment: I was wrong, it looks like the problem was caused by different vimrc files... (checked with `:version`, I had no idea there were multiple, in my case `/etc/.vimrc` contained `set clipboard=unnamed`` causing the problem). I'm wondering if the fact that I recently installed neovim aside vim caused that...
https://imgur.com/a/uNWEU5O

Answer (score 1):

Hmm… the whole point of `set clipboard=unnamedplus` is *precisely* to synchronize register `""` with register `"+` so that `y` yanks *to* the system clipboard and `p` puts *from* the system clipboard.

Therefore,

> For example, after I use "yy" or "dw" my clipboard content is replaced with corresponding text.

seems to describe a perfectly working setup that does what you ask it to do. I'm not sure what you want to fix, here.

What sounds strange, though, is this:

> I noticed that after using `:set clipboard=unnamedplus`, the paste command inserts clipboard text instead of default register text, unless register is specified. For example, this inserts the right text after using `yy`:
>
> ```
> ""p
> ```
>
> And this inserts the clipboard:
>
> ```
> p
> ```

With `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, both `p`, `"+p`, and `""p` should put the exact same text.

The command is "put", by the way, not "paste".

So, what do you want, exactly? That `""` and `"+` are always synchronized or that they are never synchronized?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. My goal is to make them never synchronised. I confused the meaning of `clipboard=unnamedplus`.

Comment: They are never synchronized unless you tell Vim to. If you don't want that synchronization, don't change the default value of `clipboard`.